# pgAdmin4 will open as if it was a book after switching desktop environments

Tags: postgresql, database, pgadmin

I use KDE Plasma on Ubuntu. I started a session on regular Ubuntu desktop then switched back. Now, pgAdmin will open on Calibre (ebook management sofware). I tried running `pgadmin4` directly on the terminal and this is what I get:

```
command= "ebook-edit --detach %f" args= ("ebook-edit --detach %f", "http://127.0.0.1:42711/?key=d30dccfe-ef9e-4814-8e79-8a04465afa1d")

Copying QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:42711/?key=d30dccfe-ef9e-4814-8e79-8a04465afa1d")  to 
QUrl("file:///home/user/.cache/kioexec/krun/5762_0/unnamed")

Telling kioexecd to watch path "/home/user/.cache/kioexec/krun/5762_0/unnamed" dest "http://127.0.0.1:42711/?key=d30dccfe-ef9e-4814-8e79-8a04465afa1d"

All files downloaded, will call slotRunApp shortly

EXEC "/bin/ebook-edit --detach /home/user/.cache/kioexec/krun/5762_0/unnamed"
EXEC done
```